# Viewexpiredexception :No save view state could be found for identifier.though i have used client in web.xml

Tags: jsf-2, tomcat7

I am developed a tool in `JSF`,with `UI` in `.xhtml`.The tool is working fine in eclipse.Once i deployed in production server i got `VIEWEXPIRED` exception[`no saved view state would be found for the identifier:`] often.Once i cleared the cookies and run the tool,the tool was wroking for 70%.

I have used @view scope in managed bean in faces-config.
So i did the changes by 
using `STATE_SAVING_METHOD` as client in `web.xml`.

Though i deployed and restart the server still I am facing the same issue.
I am sitting with  this issue for more than a week.
Anyone help me for solving this issue.
Kindly help me by solving this issue in jsf itself.

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please look into this thread(in case if you have missed this link) : [jsf vewexpiredexception][1]

i also faced the same issue. There can be multiple reasons for getting this exception. Scope of the bean should not play a role in this. 
Solution 1.Add this code in your web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.numberOfViewsInSession</param-name>
    <param-value>150</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.numberOfLogicalViews</param-name>
    <param-value>150</param-value>
</context-param>
```

default is 15, u can use some higher value.

Solution 2: Add this line to web.xml, Default is server, change it to client

```
<context-param>
 <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
<param-value>server</param-value>
</context-param>
```

For me 1st solution worked.

Comment: Thanks for your response... I have already watched this link..and am not getting the conlusion.Still am facing with this issue.Can u tell me what the benefit of viewscope or else request scope.am in a idea to change to request scope in managed bean,kindly let me know..whether by adding request scope will avoid this exception